# Fails while running testng annotations

Tags: testng

This issue has been bugging me for the last few days, and I couldn't solve it on my own, take into account, I am new to TestNg, the issue is that when I create a simple java project and add TestNg dependency, then when I run the program, it generates me this error below, yes I looked into previous forum similar to this issue nothing resolves, and I am using IntelliJ editor, please if anyone can help me out could be grateful

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/beust/jcommander/ParameterException
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:105)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: Can you please share the source code snippet to debug and reproduce above issue?

Comment: Yes Bipin thank you import org.testng.annotations.Test;

/**
 * Unit test for simple App.
 */
public class AppTest 
{

    @Test
    public void shouldAnswerWithTrue()
    {
        System.out.println("Hi");
    }
}
this is the code

Comment: Please google search sample tutorials on TestNG to get started with and follow the steps to configure your project.